# Accessing class variable based on user input

Tags: python, class, jira

I want to able to access class variables based on the user input since I get a class from JIRA API call. For example

```
test = my_jira.issue("ISSUE-1799")
test.fields.summary = "Test issue" # sets summary field

# user can enter anything here and I can access any variable from test.fields.
random = "summary"
print(test.fields.(random)) # prints "Test issue"
```

Is this possible? There is a bunch of class variables in `test.field` and I want to be able to access whichever one based on whatever the user enters. Sorry if this is incorrect. I don't really know how to describe this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can use the builtin function [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) like this:

```
print(getattr(test.fields, random))
```

Comment: This is a poor answer. It doesn't address the 3rd argument of `getattr` and it lazily dumps in poor coding practices that were used. It also assumes that `test.fields` is not a `dict`.

Comment: This is an objective answer, it answers the question and it links to the docs if he needs more info. The code snippet is clearly a representation and not the actual application. `test.fields` is a JIRA object from Jira SDK, and OP mentioned he gets "a class from JIRA API Call" .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr` to get attributes from a class. The third argument is a default argument that will be returned if the attribute does not exist. Considering you want to allow users to type in the attribute they want to access, you should definitely make use of the 3rd argument and be prepared to pass a message to the user if the attribute does not exist. Otherwise, mistakes will lead to errors breaking your script.

If `test.fields` is **not** a `dict`:

```
#example
attrName = input("Type the attribute name you would like to access: ")
attr = getattr(test.fields, attrName, None)

if attr is None:
    print(f'Attribute {attrName} does not exist')
else:
    print(f'{attrName} = {attr}')
```

if `test.fields` is a `dict`:

```
attrList = [*test.fields]  #list of keys
attrName = input("Type the attribute name you would like to access: ")

if attrName in attrList:
    attr = test.fields[attrName]
    print(f'{attrName} = {attr}')
else:
    print(f'Attribute {attrName} does not exist')
```

You should note that `random` is a python module. It is not good practice to use common module names as variable names. If you happened to import `random` for anything connected to this script you could have problems.